# Disable pdf upload for Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm developing an application that uses a web browser that always needs to display a specific screen. I found out that I can drag and drop a file(.pdf for example) and it will render the .pdf over my screen. Is there a way to disable file upload(or at least .pdf uploads) for the chromium browser. I know that Chrome has this function, so I am hoping I can do this too in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this problem, thought someone else might find it useful:

In C++ CefDragHandler::OnDragEnter has to be implemented.

For C#: CefSharp::IDragHandler::OnDragEnter is the equivalent and it must return true to disable the "drag and drop" action.